# How to convert string "85,123kg" to integer 85? Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, basic

I'm using 2012 Microsoft Visual Basic for Application 7.1

I have a bunch of strings like `"85,123kg"` , `"123,05kg"`, `"11,21kg"`.

And I want to convert it to Integers like `85`, `123`, `11`

How can I do it?

Now I'm trying to `For` every string and when `","` detects - `Exit for` And all numbers before the `","` add to new string

But this looks awfull

```
If InStr(text, "kg") > 0 Then
        For charIndex = 1 To text.Length
            If text(charIndex) Like "," Then
            Exit For
            Else
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Basic for Application 7.1 has a function named `Val` that does exactly that. You would use it as `Val("85,123kg")` (or `Val(text)` where *text* is equal to "85,123kg") and obtain the integer 85.

The `Val` function tries to extract a number from the string starting from the left. It will ignore whitespace (spaces and tabs) and linefeeds.
Reading stops at the first character that cannot be recognized as part of a number. Symbols and characters that are often considered parts of numeric values, such as dollar signs and commas, are not recognized.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.val?view=net-6.0